# Simple select query taking too long

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with around 18k rows for a certain week and another week has 22k rows.

I'm using view and indexes to retrieve the data like so

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM my_view 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN @date1 AND
@date2
```

But somehow, the week with 22k retrieves data faster (around 3-5sec) while the other takes a minute at least. These causes my wcf to timeout. What am i missing?

Comment: Have you checked the execution plans for your query to see if the indexes are being used?

Comment: How do you expect getting an answer without giving the table definitions and the corresponding indexes?

Comment: What does this question have to do with WCF?

Comment: @hugh the query taking too long causes timeout on the wcf

Comment: @MiikaL. i've confirmed that it uses the indexes for both queries

Comment: Post the execution plans. Also without `ORDER BY`. It is not guaranteed what 100 matching rows you will get.

Comment: If you could also post your view definition as well?

Comment: Please also post the view. How many records do you have in the entire table? - this will also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply an index on timestamp field.

if you have already an index on timestamp then check the index being used for this query in execution plan.

The index hint will only come into play where your query involves joining tables, and where the columns being used to join to the other table matches more than one index. In that case the database engine may choose to use one index to make the join, and from investigation you may know that if it uses another index the query will perform better. In that case you provide the index hint telling the database engine which index to use.

Sample code use index hints:

```
select [Order].[OrgId], [OrderDetail].[ProductId]
  from [Order] 
 inner join [OrderDetail] **with(index(IX_OrderDetail_OrderId))** on [Order].[OrderId] = [OrderDetail].[OrderId]
```